# Using Pub/Sub and Long Polling

Tags: architecture, chat, scalability

I want to implement a scalable chat application.
Therefore, I would like to use the pub/sub technique (when someone sends a message, its  been sent to the whole room). Because of its simplicty, I chose Redis cache server.

In addition, I would like to use long polling to transfer the new messages from server to client. The reason I am not using web sockets is because I can have some troubles in organization's proxies.

As far as I read over the web, it sounds like standard solution for the problem.

Can you please advice what is the best solution to handle the messages that are been sent between the long poll requests? How the user doesn't miss a message?

It sounds like I need to save a cache for each client, containing his own messages. but this way - I am not leverage the pub/sub technique. Instead of pub/sub, I can send message to each user in the room.

Comment: If this is still of interest, the following Go library handles exactly this situation abstracting away pubsub+longpoll from the actual web server, thus it does not matter which protocol you wrap around it, http, ws, amqp or anything else: https://github.com/ventu-io/go-longpoll

Answer (score 2):

Using a long polling approach, the client might make API calls to your server like this (in this example to see all chats in room 1034, which already has 3 chats in it):

```
GET /rooms/1034/chats
```

Since there is data to be had, your server responds straight away.

Response:

```
{
  "chats": [
    { "sequence": 0, "by": "fred", "message": "hey guys, anyone in this room?" },
    { "sequence": 1, "by": "fred", "message": "anyone at all?" },
    { "sequence": 2, "by": "bill", "message": "yeah I'm here!" }
  ]
}
```

Now the client can display the three chats, and then ask the server for more. This is where the long polling kicks in - since the server has no more chats, the API call blocks until a new chat arrrives.

```
GET /rooms/1034/chats?after=2
```

.. server blocks until someone adds a new chat ..

Response:

```
{
  "chats": [
    { "sequence": 4, "by": "frodo", "message": "I'm here too!" }
  ]
}
```

The key point is that the client itself maintains a "cursor" of where it is, so you don't need to maintain any per-client cache, etc. on the server.

Of course there's more to it. The server cannot block forever, so after some time (maybe 60 seconds) it should reply, but with a timeout message.

In Spring there is support via DeferredResult for the server to handle this without tying up a whole thread per client.